# Is it possible to describe a $k$-basis for $M\otimes_{kH}N$ when $M$ is a $k[G\times H]$-module and $N$ is a $k[H\times K]$-module?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, modules

Suppose $k$ is a field for Let $M$ be a finitely-generated a $k[G\times H]$-module and let $N$ be a finitely-generated $k[H\times K]$-module. Then in particular, $M$ and $N$ are finite-dimensional $k$-vector spaces, $M$ is a $(kG,kH)$-bimodule and $N$ is a $(kH,kK)$-bimodule. Hence, we can form the tensor product $M\otimes_{kH} N$ to get a $k[G\times K]$-module. Is it possible to describe a $k$-basis for this module in terms of $k$-bases for $M$ and $N$?

Many thanks.

Comment: The groups $G$ and $K$ play no role in the final question. You are just after a $k$-basis of the $k[H]$-module obtained by tensoring two of such. Unless I have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Yes, that's right.